# Looking for hosting provider that exposes database as restful service

Tags: json, database, rest, backendless

This may be a total shot in the dark, but looking for a service that basically exposes a database model as a restful service which we can query from the front-end (eliminating the need for a middle layer/server).

The idea would be simple enough, create a database with say a products table. This would then be exposed automatically via an API that represents that table. On your front end the user could enter text or choose several options and then via JS you could hit that endpoint (with the user's choices as parameters which inevitably becomes a SELECT and retrieves the data), that returns some JSON back in the form of results and via JS you display it on the front-end.

I have to believe something like this exists and maybe I am not being clear enough, but its basically an auto-created backend. This would be great for rapid prototyping.

Thanks in advance if anyone has ideas!

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking us to recommend a software package or a company that provides a specific service. If it's the former, you need to ask on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). If the latter, then you are probably not going to get an answer here. We just deal with programming errors.

Comment: @MaxZoom Thanks for that, Parse actually did some of this prior so its not unheard of.

Comment: @MickSharpe Actually looking more SaaS based, like Parse or Firebase. I will move it over there. Appreciate it!

Comment: There's actually a bunch of such services listed here after the Parse's announcement: https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives

Comment: @scadge thanks very much!